# Cannot resolve symbol 'Spinner'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm just trying to screw around in Android Studio and at the moment, I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected text of a spinner.

Here is my relevant code

```
package dgameman1.com.emojifixer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    

        Spinner  emojiSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.emojiSpinner);
        final String selectedSpinnerText = emojiSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Button installNewEMojis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.installEmojisButton);
        installNewEMojis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, selectedSpinnerText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

            }
        });


    }

}
```

The issue I have right now is with this

```
Spinner  emojiSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.emojiSpinner);
String selectedSpinnerText = emojiSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

'Spinner' is a red color and when I over my mouse over it, I get the error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Spinner'

Comment: Well, I notice you're not importing any class named `Spinner`...

Comment: `import android.widget.Spinner;` Omg. I'm so stupid. This is my first time using Android Studio. I've only really used Visual Studio for c# and I just assumed it would automatically import like Visual Studio does. Is there anyway to automatically do imports?

Comment: I use Eclipse, not IDEA, but I would expect that if you autocomplete the class name it'll automatically import for you.

Comment: @IdkHowToCodeAtAll Check in the Android Studio options for keymap. There you will find all the short cuts. Im using mac so i only know the short cuts for mac. But ya there are shortcuts to optimise import and include import and format your code.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild project may be help you

Comment: @IdkHowToCodeAtAll Review my answer .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Spinner'

***This means that the class has not been imported properly*** .

At First import **R**

```
import dgameman1.com.emojifixer.R
```

Then add this in your import section

```
import android.widget.Spinner;
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart** Your Project .

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't, there are other possible solutions I can add.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the `android.widget.Spinner`

Comment: OP says that he is not getting any option for importing when he mouse over the `Spinner`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed correct, even though that was the issue. Is there a reason it didn't tell me about importing Spinner even though that was the issue? It's happened the other times I've needed to import something

Comment: If you are not getting option for Importing package on mouse over then it means there is some other issue. If that issue is resolved then this issue will automatically be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

change the code if you don't want to import anything.

```
android.widget.Spinner emojiSpinner = (android.widget.Spinner)findViewById(R.id.emojiSpinner);
```